# Apply profiler template to saved log

Tags: sql-server, profiler, trace

I need to check for deadlocks in my customer's system. He provided me with unfiltered logs.

Can I filter them after running the trace somehow? (I don't have direct access to his server)

It seems like the template can be applied only before running the trace.

Comment: What format is the trace provided in? A `*.trc` file?

Comment: yes, its .trc format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can apply a template after a trace file is saved, however you can work around this by exporting the results to a table.

If you open the trace file in `SQL Profiler` and the navigate to `File > Save As > Trace Table`, you can output the result set to a table in an existing or new database and then you can query/filter the result set to your hearts content.

Comment: Or use [`sys.fn_trace_gettable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188425.aspx) to avoid having to load it all into Profiler first.